# Search location with radius (cocoa-touch)

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location

I have an array of NSDictionaries. Those dictionaries have keys Latitude and Longitude. Is it possible to search through that array for all the dictionary which lie in a certain radius from a specified location. So for example, i can specify "houston, tx" or "77381" and a radius of 500 miles and it would search through?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed do this, yes.  There may be a simpler way, but the way I've seen and used is to create a `CLLocation` instance, initialized with the latitude and longitude, then use the `distanceFromLocation:` method found in the [CLLocation Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html).  Given you have a `CLLocation` instance for your location of comparison, you can set up an if statement to query if the value returned is less than your specified distance.  Just be sure to release the temporary `CLLocation`s so as not to have any memory leaks

Comment: Almost exactly what I am looking for! Thanks. Do you know how I can convert a city/postal code to a CLLocation? THanks!

Comment: That is something that's not exactly covered as a standard option in the Core Location or MapKit frameworks.  But it is possible.  My latest app does just that for a particular part, actually.  What you will need to do is to use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).  That site helps explain what's going on.  Basically, you will send a request via `NSConnection` and `NSURLRequest`, then parse the returned data either with XML or JSON depending on your preference.  If you run into troubles with that, I'd be happy to try and guide you along

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any bundled functionality to do that.

Simply iterate/enumerate over the array to do it.
There are a dozen ways.

```
for (NSDictionary *withLatLong in arrayOfDicts) {
 // do work…
}

[arrayOfDicts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id x, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
  NSDictionary *withLatLong = (NSDictionary *)x;
  // do work…
}];

NSMutableArray newArray = [arrayOfDicts mutableCopy];
[newArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```